# Confused about execution context in JS

Tags: javascript, apply, execution, scoping

```
// Replace the method named m of the object o with a version that logs
// messages before and after invoking the original method.
function trace(o, m) {

  // Remember original method in the closure
  var original = o[m];

  // Define the new method
  o[m] = function() { 

    // Log message
    console.log(new Date(), "Entering:", m);

     // Invoke original
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments);

     // Log message
    console.log(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);

    return result;
  };
}
```

Hello! The code example given above is from my coding book. It tries to illustrate a practice called “monkey-patching” using the `apply` function in JavaScript. I'm really confused about the nature of the line where the original function is invoked:

```
var result = original.apply(this, arguments); // Invoke original.
```

As far as I understand, the call to the original function could also be written without the help of `apply()`, since the thisarg is `this`, which is to say that the execution context remains unchanged: the `original` object.

The second point of confusion is where the hell the `arguments`argument for `apply()` comes from? Yes, I know that it is an object generated at every function invocation that is used to access the function arguments - but this line is inside an anonymous function without any arguments. I don't have a clue and am grateful for any hint.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @dayuloli What would that local execution context be? To quote my book again "functions are executed using the scope chain that was in effect when they were defined.", doesn't that mean that the execution context is the one of the anonymous function?

Comment: And if the execution context is that of the anynomous function, does that then mean that the `arguments` object is empty (because the function doesn't take any arguments)? What would be the point in that? Wouldn't I want to use the arguments that the original function would have received?

Comment: "*the thisarg is `this`, which is to say that the execution context remains unchanged: the `original` object*" - No. The `original` is the function (method) reference that should get called, it's not the context. And you don't know whether the `this` context is `o` (the object on which the method was overridden) either - it could be anything. Therefore, we use `this`.

Comment: "*the `arguments` object is generated at every function invocation and is used to access the function arguments - but this line is inside an anonymous function without any arguments*" - no, the anonymous function did not declare any *parameters*. That doesn't mean it could not be invoked with arbitrarily many arguments.

Comment: @FlorianWicher `local execution context` means where the method is invoked i.e. if `m` is invoked as function `this` is global, if `m` is invoked as a `method` of an `object`,  `this` is the `object` , if `m` is invoked inside another function `this` also refer to global

Comment: your question is crystal clear to me and I am confident I can give you explanation until you fully understand, just ask me! If you think it is helpful, please consider selecting my answer.  
@Bergi, I need a new job now and I am trying to improve my profile if you think I provide a reasonable answer and did some contribution. Please upvote, thanks!

Comment: The statement "*the execution context remains unchanged*" is incorrect. When a new function is created, a new execution context is created. The use of *apply* sets the value of *this* within the execution context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question: Why is `apply` necessary?

If you invoke `original` directly in the anonymous function, `this` inside `original` is sure to refer to `global` (`undefined` in strict mode). The anonymous function, on the other hand, is declared as a method of `o`, so if you invoke as `o.m()`, `this` inside the anonymous function should refer to `o`. Passing `o` to `original` is desired because it preserved the semantic.

In addition to binding `this`, `apply` can also convert an array of arguments to individual parameters.

```
function toBeCalled(x,y){
    console.log('x is: '+x+" y is:"+y)
}

function x (){
    toBeCalled(arguments)
    toBeCalled.apply(this,arguments)
}

x('aa','bb','vv')

//x is: [object Arguments] y is:undefined
//x is: aa y is:bb
```

See the difference?

Second question: Where is `arguments` from?

In JavaScript, `arguments` is a built-in variable within the scope of a function. The value of `arguments` can only be determined **when the function is invoked**, it is not fixed at all.

```
function x (){
    console.log(arguments)
}

x('aa','bb','vv')
x("ff","dd")
x(1123)
```

`arguments` is assigned a value when `x` is invoked, it is dynamic.